# jQuery Validate two fields from one or another section

Tags: jquery, validation

I have done some research on the above and found that I am able to use errorPlacement and some commands in order to achieve a portion of my work.

However; what I have is the following:

Option 1 - Two fields
Option 2 - Two fields

Depending if a user has the need for option 1 or 2, they need to enter both fields for EACH option they have chosen.

For example

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<div id="option1">
<input type="text" id="number" name="field1">
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="field2">
</div>
<div id="option2">
<input type="text" id="cardnumber" name="field3">
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="field4">
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

So basically, if the user decides option 1 is best for them, both number and firstname need to be validated. If they choose option2, both cardnumber and firstname need to be validated.

Comment: How user going to select one option out of this two options ?

Comment: user is presented the form - and can visually choose one or two - so all fields are displayed, IF field1 is captured then field2 must be captured too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function validate() {
    var number = $("#number").val();
    var numberFirstName = $("#firstname").val();
    var cardNumber = $("#cardnumber").val();
    var cardNumberFirstName = $("#c_firstname").val();

    if (number != "" && numberFirstName == "") {
        alert("Complete both fields on Option 1");
    }

    if (cardNumber != "" && cardNumberFirstName == "") {
        alert("Complete both fields on Option 2");
    }
}
```

Note that you can't have the same id property for 2 different elements. So I changed "Option 2 firstname id" to "c_firstname".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .required() method with a callback. Take a look at this example:
  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression

Comment: while this helped - its below my pay grade ;)